# How do i get the whole last month in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

Hey Thank you for taking some time out to read my question.

What I would like to do is extract the whole last month. As an example for the month of September, 2018 (2018-09-01 - 2018-09-30) and today date is

> Sys.Date()
>   [1] "2018-10-05"

```
`lst %>%
    mutate(taskDate = as.Date(taskDate)) %>%
    filter(taskDate >= as.Date(Sys.Date() %m-% months(1), '%Y%m%d')) %>%
    filter(taskDate != as.Date(Sys.Date(), 'month')) %>%
    select('taskMinutes','taskBillable') %>%
    group_by(taskBillable) %>%
    summarise(total = sum(as.numeric(taskMinutes))) %>%
    mutate(total = (total/60)) %>%
    mutate(total= as.numeric(total))`
```

This code get the next outcome  "2018-09-05" - "2018-10-05"
And what i want is get just last month such is 2018-09-01 - 2018-09-30

what could I do ?

## Data

```
taskDate    taskMinutes taskBillable
2018-09-24T00:00:00 180 FALSE
2018-09-24T00:00:00 390 TRUE
2018-09-24T00:00:00 540 FALSE
2018-09-21T00:00:00 60  TRUE
2018-09-24T00:00:00 30  FALSE
2018-09-24T00:00:00 30  FALSE
2018-09-24T00:00:00 120 TRUE
2018-09-25T00:00:00 390 TRUE
2018-09-25T00:00:00 480 TRUE
2018-09-21T00:00:00 240 TRUE
2018-09-21T00:00:00 240 FALSE
2018-09-24T00:00:00 60  TRUE
2018-09-25T00:00:00 60  TRUE
2018-09-26T00:00:00 30  TRUE
2018-09-26T00:00:00 480 FALSE
2018-09-24T00:00:00 240 TRUE
2018-09-25T00:00:00 240 TRUE
2018-09-27T00:00:00 360 TRUE
2018-09-27T00:00:00 150 TRUE
2018-09-27T00:00:00 480 TRUE
2018-09-27T00:00:00 90  TRUE
2018-09-26T00:00:00 60  TRUE
2018-09-26T00:00:00 240 TRUE
2018-09-27T00:00:00 180 TRUE
2018-10-02T00:00:00 30  TRUE
2018-10-02T00:00:00 60  FALSE
2018-10-02T00:00:00 540 FALSE
2018-10-02T00:00:00 480 TRUE
2018-09-28T00:00:00 180 TRUE
2018-09-27T00:00:00 15  FALSE
2018-09-28T00:00:00 15  FALSE
2018-09-28T00:00:00 120 TRUE
2018-09-28T00:00:00 30  TRUE
2018-09-27T00:00:00 210 TRUE
2018-09-28T00:00:00 30  FALSE
2018-10-03T00:00:00 60  TRUE
2018-09-28T00:00:00 480 TRUE
2018-10-01T00:00:00 480 TRUE
2018-10-01T00:00:00 456 FALSE
```

Comment: Although I am not sure of what you have asked, but there are two functions in lubridate package, `floor_date(Sys.Date() , "month")` and `ceiling_date(Sys.Date(), "month") - 1`, you may try those. In case you want to go to previous month, then use `-months(1)`  to subtract the month.I hope this helps thanks

Comment: I have edited my question, I sow that i didn't really explained it properly. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lubridate and filter, make sure you use the right >=, < operators to capture the whole month properly.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- read.table(text =
"taskDate    taskMinutes taskBillable
2017-10-05T00:00:00 210 TRUE
2017-10-06T00:00:00 30  TRUE
2017-10-16T00:00:00 60  TRUE
2017-10-18T00:00:00 120 TRUE
2017-10-19T00:00:00 120 TRUE
2017-10-25T00:00:00 60  TRUE
2017-10-26T00:00:00 120 TRUE
2017-11-01T00:00:00 60  TRUE
2017-11-02T00:00:00 60  TRUE
2017-11-03T00:00:00 30  TRUE
2017-10-30T00:00:00 60  TRUE
2017-10-30T00:00:00 120 TRUE
2017-10-31T00:00:00 60  TRUE",
                 header = T,
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

# convert taskDate to date format
df$taskDate <- gsub("T", " ", df$taskDate) %>% ymd_hms()

str(df)

# 'data.frame': 13 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ taskDate    : POSIXct, format: "2017-10-05" "2017-10-06" "2017-10-16" ...
#  $ taskMinutes : int  210 30 60 120 120 60 120 60 60 30 ...
#  $ taskBillable: logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...

# filter 0 note the (- years(1) + months(1)) could be removed, but is needed for the sample data
filter(df,
       taskDate >= floor_date(Sys.Date(), "month") - months(1) - years(1) + months(1),
       taskDate < ceiling_date(Sys.Date(), "month") - months(1) - years(1) + months(1))

#      taskDate taskMinutes taskBillable
# 1  2017-10-05         210         TRUE
# 2  2017-10-06          30         TRUE
# 3  2017-10-16          60         TRUE
# 4  2017-10-18         120         TRUE
# 5  2017-10-19         120         TRUE
# 6  2017-10-25          60         TRUE
# 7  2017-10-26         120         TRUE
# 8  2017-10-30          60         TRUE
# 9  2017-10-30         120         TRUE
# 10 2017-10-31          60         TRUE
```

Comment: I have tried filter(df,
       date >= floor_date(Sys.Date(), "month") - months(1),
       date < ceiling_date(Sys.Date(), "month") - months(1)).

However, is still getting part of the actual month not just last month 
Outcome( 2018-09-08 to 2018-10-08) and i want to get ( 2018-09-01 to 2018-09-30)

Comment: What format is your date column in? Please supply some of your data. When I copy the answer into my R I get the expected outcome.

Comment: I have add a sample to the question at the top, Thanks for tracking up my question!

Comment: It's best to use `dput()` when supplying sample data, that way we can see how it is formatted. My updated solution takes the character, converts to date format and applies filter (note your sample data is for Oct/Nov 2017 data for Sep 2018 would be more representative for your question).

Comment: Thanks Paul you have been really helpfull I have change the data to be from this year, I will have a go to your code and check it out! Thanks hips